# Which plugins make assumptions about current directory

Tags: vim

I'm thinking about setting the following in `vimrc`

```
set autochdir
```

In [**vim.wikia.com**](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file) it states that

> ...Unfortunately, when this option is set some plugins may not work
>   correctly if they make assumptions about the current directory....

Am I better just changing the working directory manually when required? Which plugins will not work properly when using `autochdir`?

Comment: Just do it, things won't blow in your face.

Comment: @romainl - nice we're still speaking!! - I'm just after ideas on which plugins it might impact. Sounds like (via Ingo) that it'll help most of the time with unexpected results being rare. It was all I needed to fix the problem that I posted yesterday - the one you answered "You've got to be kidding...". My background is non IT with 10 years of MS Office + SSMS so you need to understand this is a whole new world for me...

Comment: Sorry for my lack of patience but it is my belief that breaking things is a good way to know how they work.

Comment: @romainl good to have attitude: I believe that if I have a question then I'll ask it. I'm just glad we're still on speaking terms...thought it was the last straw yesterday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using `:set autochdir` since I've started with Vim in 2002, I use a lot of plugins, but I haven't experienced many problems. (And those problems were rather easy to fix; I think I've sent some such patches to plugin authors.)

In the end, it greatly depends on the individual plugins. Don't be afraid and just try it; it's trivial to switch back, anyway. Look out for problems with plugins that create new buffers or access / navigate to other buffers, especially when those are distributed over different directories. Problems ususally manifest themselves into the wrong buffer (or an empty one in the wrong directory) being opened.

Comment: +1 thanks Ingo (for your patience more than anything) - I'll use the setting: not sure whether to delete this post -3 is pushing it

Comment: @whytheq Your question is a wrong fit for SO; you might have polled users on IRC or vim_use to report problematic plugins instead. A better question for SO would be: "Plugin XYZ doesn't work with autochdir, how do I fix this?"

Comment: ...no problem - I will keep this post as the down-votes are not a problem. I might edit the question a little to see if I can encourage some up-votes to even things out!